# How does PyPI decide what is the latest version of a package?

Tags: python, package, pypi

I've recently uploaded an upgrade to a package I developed on PyPI, version `0.4.3`. The next day I noticed a minor adjustment I forgot to add, and uploaded a new version, `0.4.3a0`. Yet, PyPI kept marking the previous one as the latest version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/version-specifiers/#version-specifiers) [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/), under which [`0.4.3a0` is read as a *pre*-release](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#pre-releases) (specifically, an alpha) of version `0.4.3`.

> Within a numeric release `(1.0, 2.7.3)`, the following suffixes are permitted and MUST be ordered as shown:
>
> ```
> .devN, aN, bN, rcN, <no suffix>, .postN
> ```

Consider using version [`0.4.3post1`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#post-releases) or just `0.4.4`.